# Access SSM parameters from parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-ssm

I have SAM template which deploys few lambdas and I would like to use some parameters I created in SSM parameters store.

I created 2 parameters for my tests:

- `/test/param` which is a simple string
- `/test/param/encrypt` which contains the same string as `/test/param` but is encrypted by a KMS key

In my SAM template, I'm trying to get the the value of `/test/params` by following [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/). Here is a snipper of my template:

```
Parameters:
  AuthPasswordPublic:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    NoEcho: true
    MinLength: 8
    Description: Password for the "public" part of the website
    Default: /test/param

...

Resources:
  Auth:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Handler: auth.handler
      CodeUri: ./dist
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PASSWORD_PUBLIC: !Ref AuthPasswordPublic
          SEED: !Ref AuthSeed
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /auth
            Method: post
```

This should theoretically works when deployed onto AWS. However, I would like to test it locally first. I'm already `aws-sam-local` and my credentials are properly configured on my local machine as I'm able to use the AWS CLI. But when running this locally, the value of the envvar `PASSWORD_PUBLIC` is empty. I tested both the plain text en encrypted SSM parameters but the results are the same.

I would suspect that `aws-sam-cli` does not support SSM parameters yet but couldn't find any information about that online, nor on the GitHub issues/PR. Any ideas of what is going on here?

Comment: try using [serverless-offline](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-using-the-ssm-parameter-store).

Answer (score 1):

`aws-sam-cli` uses the `docker-lambda` container, which according to the [docs](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) creates:

> A sandboxed local environment that replicates the live AWS Lambda environment almost identically...

This means that components such as AWS SSM are not re-created within the docker container. You can check the open Github issue [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/616).

So you may have to resort to retrieving the SSM parameters from the host (with `aws cli` configured), and pass them into the container when invoking sam-cli:

```
PASSWORD_PUBLIC=$(aws ssm get-parameter --with-decryption --name "/test/param/encrypt") sam local start-api
```